# My js file is not loading when using in the EJS template but CS file is loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, ejs

Here is the EJS template file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css" />
<div id="home-container">
  <section id="feed-posts">
    <h3>Posts</h3>
    <form action="/posts/create" id="new-post-form" method="POST">
      <textarea
        name="content"
        id=""
        cols="30"
        rows="3"
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        required
      ></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
    <div class="posts-list-container">
      <ul>
        <% for(post of posts) {%> <%- include('_post')-%> <%}%>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="user-friends">
    <h3>Friends</h3>
    <% for(u of all_users) {%>
    <p>
      <a href="/users/profile/<%= u.id %>"><%= u.name %></a>
    </p>
    <%}%>
  </section>
</div>
<script src="/js/home_posts.js"></script>
```

Here is home_posts.js:

```
//method to submit the form data for new post using ajax
{
  let createPost = function () {
    let newPostForm = $("#new-post-form");
    newPostForm.submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/posts/create",
      data: newPostForm.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (err) {
        console.log(err.responseData);
      },
    });
  };
  console.log("hello");
  createPost();
}
```

Here is the index.js that my app is pointing to:

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const port = 8000;
const app = express();
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const db = require("./config/mongoose");
//used for session cookie
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocal = require("./config/passport-local-strategy");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
const sassMiddleware = require("node-sass-middleware");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const customMware = require("./config/middleware");

app.use(
  sassMiddleware({
    src: "./assets/scss",
    dest: "./assets/css",
    debug: false,
    outputStyle: "expanded",
    prefix: "/css",
  })
);

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static("./assets"));
app.use(expressLayouts);

//extract style and script from subpages into layout
app.set("layout extractStyles", true);
app.set("layout extractScripts", true);

//set up the view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "./views");

app.use(
  session({
    name: "codeial",
    //TODO change the secret when deploying to production
    secret: "something",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
    },
    store: new MongoStore(
      {
        mongooseConnection: db,
        autoRemove: "disabled",
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log(err, " Error encountered connect-mongo setup ok");
      }
    ),
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());
app.use(customMware.setFlash);
//use express router
app.use("/", require("./routes"));

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Error encountered while starting the app ${err}`);
  }
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I tried changing the relative path.
I tried using incognito mode, different browser, reloading multiple times, restarting the server but nothing worked.

I am expecting it to prevent the default function for now, i am not getting any error or anything else.

Comment: What does it load instead of the JS file? If you open `http://localhost:8000/js/home_posts.js` in your browser, what do you see? What is the actual filesystem path for your JS file relative to `index.js`? It should be `assets/js/home_posts.js`

Comment: Shouldn't your `$.ajax()` call be **inside** the _submit_ event listener?